# (Unity 5) Projector Cookie has texture "edges"

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the cookie texture I'm using for my projector:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/huBt3.jpg

And here is the result in game:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY1Yq.jpg

It's hard to see, but there's a slight glow protruding from the four cardinal directions of the projection.  It's hard to see while standing still, but glaringly apparent when the character is in motion.

I suspect that this is because the texture is being altered internally, and the edges are being blurred with nothing, producing a slight non-black value for those edge pixels.  I haven't been successful in removing them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: post an extreme close up of the problem. i can see nothing.  note, you can click Edit and use the "image" button to put it right in there

Comment: Have you tried changing the filters on the texture (point vs bilinear vs trilinear). This setting controls how the texture is rendered and will try to blend pixels if 'point' is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the cookie image.  The pixels along the border weren't all pure-black, specifically where the circle is closest to the edges.  In Unity Projectors, I guess this results in the edge pixels being projected indefinitely, which created "rays" from my circle.  Making sure that the edge pixels in the cookie PNG were all pure-black fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mipmaps, change the texture to advanced and disable mip maps.